# PFQueryTableView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parsing, uitableview

Hi Im developing an app with Parse and a     PFQueryTableViewCotroller but I'm not able to get it working. Here's some code hope you guys can find the problem.

```
ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface ContainerViewController : PFQueryTableViewController

@end

ViewController.m

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Tider";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"Tid";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 10;
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

 //If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
 //and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
 query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
 }


[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

return query;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}



UILabel *tid = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
tid.text = [object objectForKey:@"Tid"];

UILabel *mandag_fredag = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:2];
mandag_fredag.text = [object objectForKey:@"Mandag_Fredag"];

UILabel *lordag = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:3];
lordag.text = [object objectForKey:@"Lordag"];

UILabel *sondag = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:4];
sondag.text = [object objectForKey:@"Sondag"];

return cell;
}

- (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

I have set the label tags properly and the cell identifier to @"Cell".

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to build the project? or are you encountering a crash?

If its a crash it could be due to dependancies on other classes in your data model.

To get this working, Try using queryForTable method and include the keys that have dependanices.

For Instance if i have a key named owner which has a dependancy on other class. Your method should look like:

-(PFQuery *)queryForTable {

PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

[query includeKey:@"owner"];

return query;

}

Comment: Hi yeah the app crashes even after trying your method the error I'm getting is int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
    }